# How to select text between curly brackets in sublime text?

Tags: editors, sublime-text

I am using sublime-text as an editor for my document.

There is already a short-cut for the selection of the text in between `()` as `ctrl`+ `shift` + `m`

I would like to select the text in between the curly brackets `{}`.

Does anybody know how can I do that ?

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+Shift+m work as well?  Or try Ctrl+Shift+space

Comment: well yes! Cctrl+Shift+Space works (though selection includes the curly brackets too, which is no problem at all). Ctrl+Shift+m does not work for me. Thanks!